# ffmpeg : how to move text position every 30 seconds with drawtext filter?

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like with ffmpeg drawtext filter to move one text which is bottomleft to bottomright after 30 seconds. This must running during all the live stream and and not only one time at startup.

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/36362443/5726027

Comment: Hi Gyan, thanks for your help. I've tested this exemple with three textes, My need is to have two textes.They should appear 30 seconds on each place bottom left and after 30 seconds bottom right and after 30 seconds come back to bottom left ..etc during all the live stream. In the exemple you give, the textes disappear after 30 seconds and never come back. Thanks .

Comment: Are the 2 text that appear on the left bottom, right bottom the same text or different text?

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is late, but here it goes:

Some explanation about the functions used:

- mod(x,y) increases x until it is equal or greater than y and then returns to 0
- lt(x,y) returns 1 if x is lesser than y otherwise returns 0
- if(x,y,z) evaluates x and if it is not zero uses y, otherwise if zero uses z

  ffplay -f lavfi "color=color=blue:size=900x500,drawtext=text='Some text':font='time new roman':fontsize=42:fontcolor=white:x='if(lt(mod(t,60),30),0,W-tw)':y=H-th"